What is the meaning of "~." in vpn dns settings
When running resolvectl while a VPN is connected, the DNS Search field has the entry "~." .. what is the meaning of that character sequence?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.network.5.html

Domains=
….
The "routing-only" domain "~."  (the tilde indicating
definition of a routing domain, the dot referring to the DNS
root domain which is the implied suffix of all valid DNS
names) has special effect. It causes all DNS traffic which
does not match another configured domain routing entry to be
routed to DNS servers specified for this interface. This
setting is useful to prefer a certain set of DNS servers if a
link on which they are connected is available.


This setting is read by systemd-resolved.service(8). "Search
domains" correspond to the domain and search entries in
resolv.conf(5). Domain name routing has no equivalent in the
traditional glibc API, which has no concept of domain name
servers limited to a specific link.

